# How to create a list of all visible elements in a class python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am using python 3.x Selenium WebDriver and I am making a for loop to go all through the elements of the page with limit the length of the elements in the class and then print number of iteration but it gets all visible and hidden elements how to get only visible element in the page.

To get all elements from the class I am using

```
showMore = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('getPhotos')
```

Comment: is_displayed method work with only (find element) and not the list (find elements)

Comment: you could iterate through the list then insert each element into the new list if is_displayed = true? that's my last guess on this because I haven't found anything better

Comment: @L_Church And I think this is the right approach. If the element is visible, push founded element in new collection. Then, just use the collection with founded elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the list of all elements (visible and invisible) and filter it down to only those that are visible. There are several ways to do this... here is one.

```
showMore = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('getPhotos')
onlyVisible = filter(lambda x: x.is_displayed(), showMore)
```

Comment: I think the syntax is good but I don't have a way to verify right now.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to cater to your requirement will be to create a *List* inducing *WebDriverWait* with `expected_conditions` as [visibility_of_all_elements_located](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located) as follows :

```
showMore = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "getPhotos")))
```

**Note** : [visibility_of_all_elements_located](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located) refers to an expectation for checking that all elements are present on the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) of a page and are visible. Visibility means that the elements are not only **displayed** but also has a *height* and *width* that is **greater than 0**.

Comment: glad to see this got attention ^^

Comment: This will not work because according to OP there are some elements that are visible and some that are not. This EC will wait until *all* elements are visible which means it will timeout.